# set background from user gallery

Tags: android

I've tried searching this for the past few days but haven't gotten great information.

If anybody could even just point me in the right direction, it would be much appreciated.

How do I give the option to have the user pick the background for the app from their own gallery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind... after I posted the question, the related topics pain on the right pointed me to this which answered my question:

[set app background from gallery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10063763/set-app-background-from-gallery?rq=1)